# What numbers fit this C pattern?

Tags: c, loops, design-patterns

So I have this `C` function that reads in 6 numbers the must fit a certain pattern to reach the end of the function successfuly.

```
void phase() {
    int numbers[6];
    read_six_numbers(numbers);
    if(numbers[0] < 0) explode();
    for(int i=1; i!=6; ++i) {
        int a = i + numbers[i-1];
        if(numbers[i]!=a) explode();
    }
}
```

What's throwing me off is the `++i` in the loop. I've looked up the difference of `++i` vs `i++` and it doesn't seem like it really matters when iterating though numbers. Yet, I can't seem to find 6 numbers that would reach the end of this function without `explode()` being called.

In short, does the `++i` vs `i++` matter in this case? Like I said, researching the difference, it doesn't seem like it should. Although when I work out the problem on paper I'm unable to reach the end of the loop successfully, so I must be doing something wrong? Or maybe just overthinking the question?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The `for` loop doesn't do anything with the value of the expression after the second `;`, it just executes it. The difference between `++i` and `i++` is solely one of return value, and since the return value isn't used, it doesn't matter.

Comment: As a standalone expression, there's no difference between `++i` or `i++`.  If you were using it as part of a larger expression (such as `x = ++i`), then yes, it makes a difference.

Comment: You should indicate what you have done to work out your answer. Because yes, you probably are doing something wrong but without seeing what you think the algorithm does its hard to say what you did wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-increment vs. post-increment is not relevant in this case.

Here's one solution (0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void explode(int n) {
    printf("Exploded at %d\n", n);
}

void phase() {
    int numbers[6] = {0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15};

    if (numbers[0] < 0) explode(0);

    for (int i = 1; i != 6; ++i) {
        int a = i + numbers[i-1];
        if (numbers[i] != a) explode(i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    phase();
}
```